# conditional string replace in python

Tags: python, string

I want to replace all "No" from a data frame col. but if col consists for any other string like "No error" then it will remain as it is.

```
test = ["No","No Error"]
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["text"])
for i in range(len(data["text"])):
    if len(data["text"][i]) == 2:
       data["text"][i] = data["text"][i]).str.replace("No", "Data not available", regex=True)
    else:
       pass
print(data)
```

I'm getting an error while running the code. I'm able to get the result by using np.where but I've had several other criteria for conditional replace where "np.where" won't work. If I can make the above approach work it'll be great. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because you only replace `"No"` in cells which contain a string that is exactly 2 characters long. Remove this condition and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
test = ["No","No Error"]
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=["text"])
data['text'] = np.where(data['text'] == 'No', "Data not available", data['text'])
# OR data.text[data.text=='No'] = "Data not available" 
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
                 text
0  Data not available
1            No Error
```

Comment: Please accept(tick symbol) any one of the ans that helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
data.text.replace({"No":"Data not available"})
```

---

```
0    Data not available
1              No Error
Name: text, dtype: object
```